# Excel: show raw value of two other cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel table with three columns:

```
London     12     13
Paris      14     15
```

I want to add another column containing a string made up the value of column 2 and column 3 together, separated by a "/". Like this:

```
London     12     13    12/13
Paris      14     15    14/15
```

How do I do show the raw values, rather than calculating the fraction? If I put the formula `=B2/C2` into D2 then unsurprisingly, I just get a fraction.

Comment: Do you want to leave it at 12/13 as text or you need to use it elsewhere for any further calculations? 12/13 may also be treated as DATE by excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CONCATENATE` or `CONCAT`if you are using Excel 2016:

```
=CONCATENATE(B2,"/",C2)
```

or you can use `&`:

```
=B2 & "/" & C2
```